# Looping all .csv files in one directory through a script, and output the results of each loop into a separate .csv in different directory

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am struggling to run multiple .csv files from one directory through a script, and sending the output of each to a different directory. I am able to run the .csv files one by one, but I have 100 files that need to go through the script. Individually, it's pretty simple, I am pulling my .csv file from `Test_Folder` and sending the output of the script to `Results`:

```
bash run_example.sh Test_Folder/df1.csv >> Results/results1.csv
```

But when I attempt to run a loop for them all, I get met with some errors due to having different directories. I've tried a few different things:

```
for csvfile in Test_Folder/*.csv;
do
    bash run_example.sh $csvfile >> Results/test_results.csv
done
```

This above obviously works, but `test_results.csv` gets overwritten after each loop.

```
for csvfile in Test_Folder/*.csv;
do
    bash run_example.sh $csvfile >> "Results/results_${csvfile}.csv"
done
```

When trying to run the above, I get met with:

```
bash: Results/results_Test_Folder/df1.csv.csv: No such file or directory
```

So it appears that it's taking the path of `$csvfile` rather than just the file itself. This ends up searching for a directory that clearly doesn't exist. I have a tried a few other variations of the above code, using other SE posts as reference, but I have not seen any post that specifically mentions different directories.

I'm looking for the new directory to be populated with the same amount of `results.csv` files as input files, so `results1.csv`, `results2.csv`, and so on. Even something as simple as a number that gets incremented with each loop and added to the output file name would be perfect. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: `$(basename "${csvfile}")` gives you the file without path and with extension.

Comment: ... or `"${csvfile##*/}"` to keep it all in the shell

Comment: Thanks for both of the comments. Either one does exactly what I was looking for. I am unable to mention both of you in my comment